# updated packages in cygwin by running setup.exe but it stored in temo file

Tags: git, cygwin

I tried to update the cygwin , so ran the setup.exe and select the cygwin directory in my system.
All those package stored in

> **C:\cygwin\http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f\release**

Some temo directory, but its not settling down to the required path like in bin and all.
How to make it happen.

I am very new to this environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want git with Cygwin, you need to select it in the package listing step, when updating Cygwin:

From [Installing Git on Cygwin](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=818)

> Select the Git packages from the “Devel” category. They are :
>
> - git
> - git-completion
> - git-gui
> - git-svn (optional)
> - gitk

[image: git on Cygwin]

From [Installing git](http://oreilly.com/software-engineering/excerpts/version-control-git/installing-git.html):

> After choosing the packages you want to install, click Next a few more times until the Cygwin installation finishes. You can then start the Cygwin Bash Shell from your Start menu, which should now include the git command

[image: Cygwin shell]